# When your answer becomes unaccepted, do you received notification?

Tags: discussion, notifications, unaccepted-answer

When your answer accepted, you get notification about that.

This also happens  when your answer becomes unaccepted?

I mean, answer  was accepted and then becomes unaccepted,  you will also get notification about that on stackexchange sites?

Comment: Not directly, but you'll get notification of a rep change of -15, though that's often obscured by aggregation with other rep changes within the same timeframe, and so sometimes you have to do some forensics on your user profile to work out what specifically happened.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As correctly mentioned in [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/276429/when-your-answer-becomes-unaccepted-do-you-received-notification#comment895600_276429), there is no notification.

However, if you will periodically check your Achievements dialog, you'll notice a -15 change:

> [image]

And clicking it will take you directly to the unaccepted answer.

Note that negative reputation won't highlight the notification dialog, until there is positive change that is greater than the negative.

Comment: **First law of Moderation:** Notify user when they gain rep, but be quiet when they lose it: if you are lucky they won't notice it, and won't go ranting about it on meta.